# How do I install .Net Core on a raspberry pi 3 running arm64 os?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, asp.net-core-1.0, arm64, asp.net-core-2.0

How do I run an Asp.net application that is already been published for `linux-arm` which does not specifically mention for `armhf` which also is arm32 or arm64!?

Answer (score 1):

To answer to my own question, firstly I am new to all Asp.net, and I have recently installed 64-bit OS for the Raspberry Pi 3 from https://github.com/bamarni/pi64. I did it make a simple web server, running nginx and 64bit support for mongodb and version 3.2 support out of the box! It was working great until I tried to run .Net Core app which currently has support for only armhf which is also arm32. I followed the steps from this blog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david/2017/07/20/setting_up_raspian_and_dotnet_core_2_0_on_a_raspberry_pi which is great for a armhf OS, and every time I tried to run the app with dotnet example.dll, I keep getting error like I do not have dotnet in reference in the system but I had physical symbolic link added! Then I went back to the github page and discovered that application support for armhf should be out of the box on the arm64 OS that bamarni kindly developed on debian stretch. Still I added 
`sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:armhf`

And  notice that he had a dependency to install with libc6:armhf! Then I went back to the blogs.msdn.microsoft.com blog and tried to install the dependencies for .net core again with the commands
 `sudo apt-get install libunwind8:armhf
 sudo apt-get install libunwind8:armhf gettext:armhf`

and then went to the folder where I have run dotnet application.dll before and this time it worked!! Sadly I shortly after ran into Sql3 dependencies problem or something similar, but hey just google the problem like we all do and there is a solution to remove the Sql dependency and install Sql-lite using dotnet command. I am a noob and learning the way all these things working. I hope this helps someone along the way! Also hope someone with more knowledge explains things a bit more in sense than I did.